# Installing php 5.2 in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php5, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to install php 5.2 following approach 3 from here : http://2bits.com/drupal-planet/various-ways-running-php-52-ubuntu-1004-lucid-lynx.html

But when i come to the step where i had to install php-mycrypt Package phpapi-20060613 is not installed. How do i fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, seems to cover what you have asked but have a read as it might not help you at all.

http://www.templatezine.com/2010/08/drupal-how-to-replace-php-5-3-with-php-5-2-in-ubuntu-10-4/

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out. This uses the Karmic packages which is not meant for 10.04, atleast from what i have read. But let me give it a shot.